# USSD app automation testing

Tags: java, rest-assured, ussd

I am very new to automation and API testing. My current project is USSD based for banking. I am currently testing manually by giving inputs on browser simulator and reading the console output (ssh into the server). The basic function of the API is to generate POST requests with all the parameters and send it to respective bank. I am looking to to automate this process and validate the request sent and the response received. I was thinking of using Selenium for browser automation but I have no idea how would I extract the response from the terminal to validate.

Please suggest as how I should go about this and if this is the right process. If there is any other way to handle this please suggest.

Comment: go through this : http://blog.wedoqa.com/2016/10/read-out-browser-console-logs-in-java-with-selenium-2-53-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing REST API You should use REST Assured for automated testing (postman tool) for manual testing. If You should test end to end - then Selenium is the right tool.